# Get Days and hours from two dates in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, date, date-difference

I am trying to get Days,hours from two dates.I searched for the solution and try some code like below but none of them returns the correct days with hours like 2 days ,3 hours.My fields values are like :

```
d1 = '2014-10-09 08:10:56';
d2 ='2014-11-09 10:10:56';



var dateDiff = function ( d1, d2 ) {
    var diff = Math.abs(d1 - d2);
    if (Math.floor(diff/86400000)) {
        return Math.floor(diff/86400000) + " days";
    } else if (Math.floor(diff/3600000)) {
        return Math.floor(diff/3600000) + " hours";
    } else if (Math.floor(diff/60000)) {
        return Math.floor(diff/60000) + " minutes";
    } else {
        return "< 1 minute";
    }
};
function DateDiff(date1, date2) {
   var msMinute = 60*1000, 
    msDay = 60*60*24*1000,
     c = new Date(),                /* now */
    d = new Date(c.getTime() + msDay - msMinute); 
    return Math.floor(((date2 - date1) % msDay) / msMinute) + ' full minutes between'; //Convert values days and return value      
}
```

what am i doing wrong.Any help thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works in all browsers.
Try this - >

```js
    d1 = '2014-10-09 08:10:56';
    d2 = '2014-11-09 10:10:56';
    var diff = dateDiff(d1,d2); 
    alert(diff);

    function splitDate(d1){
      var dSplit = d1.split(' '); 
      d = dSplit[0] + 'T' + dSplit[1];
      return d;
    }

    function dateDiff(d1,d2){
      d1 = splitDate(d1);
      d2 = splitDate(d2);
      var date1 = new Date(d1);
      var date2 = new Date(d2);
      var dateDiff = new Date(date2 - date1);    
      var diff = "Month " + dateDiff.getMonth() + ", Days " + dateDiff.getDay() + ", Hours " + dateDiff.getHours();
      return diff;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks but your code show `Month NaN, Days NaN, Hours NaN`. Did you test it ?

Comment: Firefox is unable to read the date which you have given.
where as Chrome can read it.

Comment: I checked and its working perfect in chrome.what can cause be ?

Comment: Problem was Firefox was unable to understand your date.
So i added a T between 2014-11-09 and 10:10:56.
This Firefox and Chrome both will understand.
I have changed the code please check. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you converted `d1, d2` to Date object before calling the function `dateDiff`? Because if you haven't, this line `var diff = Math.abs(d1 - d2);` won't work as expected.

UPDATE:

I'am assuming your `d1` and `d2` are in `"Y-m-d H:S:M"` format, try this:

```
function parseDate(str){
    var tmp = str.split(' ');
    var d   = tmp[0].split('-');
    var t   = tmp[1].split(':');
    return new Date(d[0], d[1]-1, d[2], t[0], t[1], t[2]);
}

function dateDiff(d1, d2){
    d1 = parseDate(d1);
    d2 = parseDate(d2);
    // ...
    // Your code continues   
}
```

Comment: @Unihedron, looks like a perfectly fine answer to me -- whether it's right or wrong is another matter, but it offers a potential solution.

Comment: @Unihedron, sorry I didn't provide a solution before, just updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I wish I could make it simpler... But this seems to work.

```
var d1 = '2014-10-09 08:10:58',
    d2 ='2015-10-09 08:10:50';

function getDateFromString(str) {
    var regexDate = /([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})/,
    values = regexDate.exec(str);
    return new Date(values[1], values[2], values[3], values[4], values[5], values[6]);
}
function daysInMonth(month,year) {
    return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
}

function dateDiff(d1,d2){
    if (d1.getTime() > d2.getTime()) {
        var oldD1 = d1;
        d1 = d2;
        d2 = oldD1;
    }
  var yearDiff = d2.getFullYear() - d1.getFullYear(),
      monthDiff = d2.getMonth() - d1.getMonth(),
      dayDiff = d2.getDate() - d1.getDate(),
      hourDiff = d2.getHours() - d1.getHours(),
      minDiff = d2.getMinutes() - d1.getMinutes(),
      secDiff = d2.getSeconds() - d1.getSeconds();

    if (secDiff < 0) {
        secDiff = 60 + secDiff;
        minDiff--;
    }
    if (minDiff < 0) {
        minDiff = 60 + minDiff;
        hourDiff--;
    }
    if (hourDiff < 0) {
        hourDiff = 24 + hourDiff;
        dayDiff--;
    }
    if (dayDiff < 0) {
        var days = daysInMonth(date2.getMonth(), date2.getFullYear());
        dayDiff = days + dayDiff;
        monthDiff--;
    }
    if (monthDiff < 0) {
        monthDiff = 12 + monthDiff;
        yearDiff--;
    }

  var diff = yearDiff > 0 ? yearDiff + " years " : "";
  diff += monthDiff > 0 ? monthDiff + " months " : "";
  diff += dayDiff > 0 ? dayDiff + " days " : "";
  diff += hourDiff > 0 ? hourDiff + " hours " : "";
  diff += minDiff > 0 ? minDiff + " minutes " : "";
  diff += secDiff > 0 ? secDiff + " seconds " : "";
  return diff;

}

var date1 = getDateFromString(d1),
    date2 = getDateFromString(d2)

document.getElementById('test').innerHTML += date1 + "<br />" + date2;

document.getElementById('test').innerHTML += "<br />" + dateDiff(date1, date2);

console.log(dateDiff(date1, date2));
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v2atzfox/)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want the difference between 2 dates.

```
var dateDiff  = function(d1/*String*/, d2/*String*/){
      var date1 = new Date(d1);
      var date2 = new Date(d2);
      var result = {
          negative:false
      };
      var diff = date1-date2;
      if(diff<0){
        result.negative = true;
        diff*=-1;
      }

      result.milliseconds = diff%1000;
      diff-=result.milliseconds;
      diff/=1000;

      result.seconds = diff%60;
      diff-=result.seconds
      diff/=60;

      result.minutes = diff%60;
      diff-=result.minutes
      diff/=60;

      result.hours = diff%24;
      diff-=result.hours

      result.days= diff/=24;
      //And so on
      return result;
}
```

Comment: I got `[object Oobject]` output.what answer should i expect ?

Comment: you are alerting output.
You can access each on by
var op = dateDiff(d1,d2);
alert(op.days|+" hours "+op.hours);

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I really understood but I think this is what you want : http://jsfiddle.net/OxyDesign/927n0L34/

JS

```
var difference = toDaysAndHours('2014-10-09 08:10:56','2014-11-09 10:10:56');

function toDaysAndHours(d1,d2){
    var dif, hours, days, difString = '';
    d1 = new Date(d1);
    d2 = new Date(d2);
    dif = Math.abs(d1 - d2);
    hours = (dif/(1000*60*60)).toFixed(0);
    days = (hours/24).toFixed(0);
    hours = hours - days*24;
    difString = days+' days, '+hours+' hours';
    return difString;
}
```

Comment: your fiddle results :`NaN days, NaN hours`

Comment: There were a comma instead of a semicolon. I fixed it. Does it work for you now ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the first function you are using strings not dates. to properly initialize a date use the constructor, as in:

```
d1 = new Date('2014-10-09 08:10:56')
d2 = new Date('2014-11-09 10:10:56')
```

Then on d1 and d2 you can use all of the get*/set* methods specified here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

While I got distracted writing the answer, I see others have said similar things, but I will add this:

The data object approach is good for understanding things, but if you want to save time use http://momentjs.com/ or a similar module to save time and mistakes.